# all user ids from passwd file not already used and within specific range

Tags: awk

I'm trying to print out all unused uid numbers from passwd file on Linux, from a range X to Y, ideally in awk language.

But I couldn't figure out how to print out all the numbers (X to Y) not in some range.

My code is here:
`awk -F: '{if ($3 >=X && $3 <=Y) { print $3} }' /etc/passwd`

It's missing the condition of all unused numbers.

Comment: how big is the typical range (X-Y) that you're looking to use?

Comment: from 1000 to 40000

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the range (X-Y) isn't huge (eg, millions), one idea:

```
awk -v x="$X" -v y="$Y" -F: '
$3>=x && $3<=y { uids[$3] }                  # if in range then save as array index
END            { for (i=x;i<=y;i++)          # loop through range and ...
                     if (! (i in uids) )     # if not an index in array then ...
                      print i                # print to stdout
               }
' /etc/passwd
```

With `X=126` and `Y=135`, and my `/etc/passwd` file stopping @ uid=131, this generates:

```
132
133
134
135
```

**NOTE:** on my system an array with 40,000 indices (per comment by OP) uses ~7 MB of memory

Answer (score 0):

You can mark all the used ones in an array, and then finally loop over the array and print the unmarked ones.

Here's a really simple example.

```
awk -F : '{ ++arr[$3] }
    END { for(i=X; i<=Y; ++i)
        if (!arr[i]) print i }' /etc/passwd
```

The size of the array could be a problem if `Y` is really large, but this should work comfortably on modern hardware and standard user ID:s.

(You could somewhat complicate the code by subtracting `X`-1 from all values, but it's probably not worth the effort.)

This script obviously doesn't have variables by these names; you'd substitute hard-coded values, or populate the variables from the calling code with `-v X=123 -v Y=456` or whatever.

Comment: Great, I was also thinking of using arrays, but haven't master them in awk yet.

Comment: It'd be more efficient to use `arr[$3]` (without `++`) and `!(i in arr)` than `++arr[$3]` and `!arr[i]` - same number of hash lookups and conditional tests but no additional arithmetic operations.

Comment: also, `!arr[i]` will create an array entry if one does not exist; for large ranges (X-Y) and a sparse array this means more memory usage

Answer (score 0):

In [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ txr uidrange.tl 0 1000000
11-12
14-32
35-37
40
42-99
128-498
501-65533
65535-1000000
```

We see here that UIDS 0 to 10 are not available, for instance.  Also 65534 is taken. This is true, though it belongs to nobody. Err, `nobody`:

```
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

The solution inserts the input range as a node into a binary search tree (ordered by the higher value) Then using the sequence of uids found in the password file, it repeatedly bisects the range, re-inserting the pieces into the search tree.

Then it traverses the nodes in order and dumps the ranges or individual values that are available.

```
(defun make-range-tree (x y)
  [tree (list x..y) to])

(defun delete-value (range-tree n)
  (iflet ((iter (tree-begin range-tree n))
          (node (tree-peek iter)))
    (match #R(@x @y) (key node)
      (when (<= x n y)
        (tree-delete range-tree y)
        (if (neql x n)
          (tree-insert range-tree x..(pred n)))
        (if (neql n y)
          (tree-insert range-tree (succ n)..y))))))

(match (@(@uid-lo (toint)) @(@uid-hi (toint))) *args*
  (flow "/etc/passwd"
    file-get-lines
    (mapcar (opip (spl ":") 2 toint))
    (let (rt (make-range-tree uid-lo uid-hi)))
    (mapdo (op delete-value rt))
    (each ((r rt))
      (match-case r
        (#R(@x @x) (prinl x))
        (#R(@x @y) (put-line `@x-@y`))))))
```

When searching the tree of ranges to see whether it has a value that lands into an existing range, we find the lowest node whose key is at least as large as the input value. Then we test whether the input value `n` actually lands in that `x`-`y` range: `(<= x n y)`. When we split that range, there are situations to handle when either partition is empty: when `n` is equal to `x` or to `y` or both.